# Extract a list of edges between community nodes and other nodes for each community

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

Suppose we have a simple weighted network on which we perform some sort of community detection. Next we extract particular community and the final task is to extract all edges between nodes of this community and all other nodes.

Below I pasted the toy code.

```
# Create toy graph
library(igraph)
set.seed(12345)
g <- make_graph("Zachary")
# Add weights to edges
E(g)$weight <- sample(x = 1:10, size = ecount(g), replace = TRUE)
# Run community detection
cl <- cluster_louvain(g)
```

There are 5 nodes which belong to community #1, 12 nodes which belong to community #2, etc.

```
> table(membership(cl))
 1  2  3  4 
 5 12  2 15
```

Now we extract community #1:

```
g1 <- induced_subgraph(g, which(cl$membership == 1))
```

Question: how to find edges which connect nodes in community #1 with all other nodes (excluding edges which define community #1)?

There is an answer related to certain community below

You start by getting all edges based in your community:

```
all_edges <- E(g)[inc(V(g)[membership(cl) == 1])]
all_edges
+ 10/78 edges:
 [1] 1-- 5 1-- 6 1-- 7 1--11 5-- 7 5--11 6-- 7 6--11 6--17 7--17
```

Then, filter out the ones that are completely internal (both vertices are in the community):

```
all_edges_m <- get.edges(g, all_edges) #matrix representation

all_edges[!(
 all_edges_m[, 1] %in% V(g)[membership(cl) == 1] & 
   all_edges_m[, 2] %in% V(g)[membership(cl) == 1]
 )] # filter where in col1 and col2
+ 4/78 edges:
[1] 1-- 5 1-- 6 1-- 7 1--11
```

But for me its necessary to get the whole list containing those nodes for each community. not only for the one. Are the any suggestions to create this loop? It would be superb if yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on your problem:

```
library(igraph) 
set.seed(12345)
g <- make_graph("Zachary")
E(g)$weight <- sample(x = 1:10, size = ecount(g), replace = TRUE)
cl <- cluster_louvain(g)
```

add membership as a vertex attribute

```
V(g)$name <- membership(cl)
```

get edgelist

```
x <- as_edgelist(g, names = T)
```

here are all edges that connect vertices of different communities

```
V(g)$name <- 1:vcount(g)
E(g)[x[,1] != x[,2]]
```

optional check

```
 E(g)$color <- ifelse(x[,1] != x[,2], "red", "blue")
 plot(g, edge.color = E(g)$color)
 plot(cl, g)
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997562/r-connecting-graphs  Thank you

Comment: This is 3 years too late, but could you explain what is going on in the function that extracts all the edges connecting vertices of different communities? I can't quite sort out the logic of why it works.

Comment: It is a shortcut that admittedly lacks clarity. It only works because the community membership is set as vertex name. In hindsight I'd recommend to set the membership as new vertex attribute `V(g)$mem` and then extract the information using `as_long_data_frame(g)`. As a result you'll have the same information in two distinct columns and won't have to alter vertices' names.

Comment: Or try this: `E(g)[which(mbs[el[,1]] != mbs[el[,2]])]`